# Why is my Ruby lookahead regex not working

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I tested my regex in rubular.com and it works, but when I run the code it behaves differently.

I want to parse whole paragraphs out of some HTML code

Here is my regex

```
description = ad_page.body.scan(/(?<=<span id="preview-local-desc">).+(?=<\/span>)/m)
```

Here is some of the HTML source

```
<span id="preview-local-desc"> I want to pick up everything typed here.
Paragraphs, everything.
</span>
```

The match begins where I need it to but then it keeps matching all the way to the end of the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the fact that [you shouldn't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/102441), you want non-greedy matching:

```
/(?<=<span id="preview-local-desc">).+?(?=<\/span>)/m
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and immediately. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use an HTML parser. I've never used ruby, but I guarantee that one exists, probably in the standard library

Comment: I will go look for one. Thank you very much I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Nokigiri is your friend here: http://nokogiri.org

Comment: +1 for link to most awesome SO thread ever.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML or HTML with a regex is marginally OK for trivial tasks, if you own or control the file's format. If you don't, then a simple change to the file could break your regex.

Using a parser will avoid that problem; I've parsed some horrible XML with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) and it didn't even notice. After writing a RSS aggregator that was handling 1000+ feeds I was hooked on using a parser.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<span id="preview-local-desc"> I want to pick up everything typed here.
Paragraphs, everything.
</span>'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
doc.at('span').text
# => " I want to pick up everything typed here.\n    Paragraphs, everything.\n    "
```

If there are multiple `<span>` tags you want:

```
doc.search('span').map(&:text)
# => [" I want to pick up everything typed here.\n    Paragraphs, everything.\n    "]
```

If there are multiple `<span>` tags and you only want this one:

```
doc.at('span#preview-local-desc').text
# => " I want to pick up everything typed here.\n    Paragraphs, everything.\n    "
```